# python - Why does emptying a list and appending to it in a function gives empty lists?

Tags: python, python-3.x

This piece of code gives empty lists in the print statement:

```
X = []
Y = []
Z = []


def DoStuff(a,b,c):
    X = []
    Y = []
    Z = []
    X.append(a)
    Y.append(b)
    Z.append(c)

DoStuff(1,2,3)

print('X:{0}\nY:{1}\nZ:{2}'.format(X,Y,Z))
```

I know I can 'fix' by adding a return-statement:

```
X = []
Y = []
Z = []


def DoStuff(a,b,c):
    X = []
    Y = []
    Z = []
    X.append(a)
    Y.append(b)
    Z.append(c)
    return X, Y, Z

X, Y, Z = DoStuff(1,2,3)

print('X:{0}\nY:{1}\nZ:{2}'.format(X,Y,Z))
```

But why does the first code gives empty lists?

Comment: Because _scope_. `X, Y, Z` in your function are different variables than the global ones. It would be _extremely_ hard to program anything non-trivial if it was not that way.

Comment: Because it creates local lists that overshadow the global ones

Answer (score 1):

Because you are defining the list at the start of the code. Also, only the second code reassign values to list

Answer (score 1):

In your first example, the [scope](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/scope-of-variables-python) of the X, Y, Z variables that you are appending is restricted to the DoStuff function.

Basically, you have two types of variables here: Inside the function and Outside the function. In your second example you are returning the values of InsideX, InsideY, InsideZ and then overwriting OutsideX, OutsideY, and OutsideZ with this line:

```
X, Y, Z = DoStuff(1,2,3)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because they are local variables. Meaning that their lifespan resides between the beginning and the end of the function block. Even though they have the same name with the global variables, they "hide" the global ones when they are within the block.

So actually you're not "emptying" the lists. If you want to modify a global variable in a function block, you can declare them as `global foo` inside the block. However, this practice is heavily discouraged in the community.